# Sort lines in text file with specific separator c

Tags: c

I have data in a text file in this format:

```
1,jack,3,7.3
2,mike,4,8.6
3,gol,2,9
```

How can I to sort the data by the last column (that represent the grades) in descending order?

Comment: Just using C? You'll have to read them in to memory, parse out and sort by the last column then write them out again. Which part are you stuck with? If you need to cope with larger files than you have memory then you'll need to be cleverer, but if it's just an assignment you probably won't have to. If it's not an assignment you can do this easier with awk and command-line sort probably.

Comment: Not the best soln: Store data in a structure and use a [sorting algorithm](https://www.google.co.in/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=sorting+laogorithms+in+C&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=cUTiUvfKLKSziAfHhoHQAw#channel=fs&q=sorting+algorithms+in+C&spell=1)

Comment: You're supposed to include your code, i.e. show us what you attempted. Not just ask for full answers without any effort.

Comment: its an assignment what i have done that i put them into array of char then i became hopeless minded case

Comment: the data was already in struct array i sorted them easy besy but the task is put them into file then read from file the data and sort them

Comment: could you help me rub its my 3rd week with c programming :) too lame

Comment: `system("perl -e 'print map $_->[0], sort{$b->[1] <=> $a->[1]} map [$_, (split /,/)[3]], <>' -- data.txt");`

Answer (score 4):

**Step one: Openning and reading**

- [`fopen`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/)
- [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/)

**Step two: Parsing**

Create a structure like:

```
struct item {
    int id;
    char name[32];
    int stat1;
    float stat2;
};
```

And fill an array of `struct item` with [`strtok`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/)

**Step three: Sorting**

Use [`qsort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/)

**Step four: Writing and closing**

- [`fprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/)
- [`fclose`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fclose/)

Comment: `fread` and `fwrite` for line-based text files, really?

Comment: This was my first idea, but your right `fgets` and `fprintf` can also being used. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you jim for concern
but could you help me more am stuck with reading process and filling the array of structs

Comment: i using fgets , fprintf and put them into array as lines

Comment: i have completed puting them into array hold each line , how to split them now and sort them

Comment: As JML wrote in step two, you can use `strtok` to separate it into all of the commas, or `strrchr` or a simple loop to find the last comma to just isolate the grade field for sorting.